# Wrap Angular App in a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am writing an AngularJS App for a system based on jQuery. Each app needs to be initiated with the code below.

How do I get this to work with my AngularJS code?

I have tried to include my entire Angular app within the function appStart(), but that doesn't work. Any ideas on how to solve this?

**Init JS:**

```
(function () {
    function appStart() {
}

function genericError() {
    console.error('Something went wrong');
}

TT.native.init()
.done(appStart)
.fail(genericError);
})();
```

**My AngularJS app:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.sortable', 'ui.router']);

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/specs');

    $stateProvider
    .state('specs', {
        url: '/specs',
        templateUrl: 'specs.html',
        controller: 'SpecsController'
    })
    .state('editSp...
```

Comment: Try angular.bootstrap(angular.element("body")[0], ['MyApplication']);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long time since I used it but this should work. It's a manual bootstrap of Angular so no ng-app in your index file.

```
(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (TT) {
            TT.native.init().done(function () {
                angular.bootstrap(document, ['myTickTailApp']);
            }).fail(function () {
                // Error handling if TickTail fails to init ...
            });
        } else {
            throw new Error('Cannot start app, tt.js not loaded');
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: Thanks! Would I place the entire Angular app inside the function appStart? or just that first line? where do I place the rest of the code then? Is it possible to keep the structure of the Tictail code as in my example? There is a possibility they will not approve the app otherwise.

Comment: You place the angular function in a separate file, like a regular app, but you _don't_ put ng-app anywhere on the document.
The `angular.bootstrap()` does that part for you manually (and when everything is loaded).

Comment: Put up some code on Github you might be able to use, or look at to get an idea: https://github.com/lowebackstrom/tictail-angular-boilerplate

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot. Very useful! Do I simply need the whole package or what code is needed for a fully functional native app, with authorization and so on?

Comment: Happy to help! The whole package gives you authorization and persistence of user data on your own backend. The server part is not necessary but removing it means rewriting some of the handshake logic in app.js. You do need mongodb and redis running on your local machine to run. When in production I used Heroku for both native and server. While developing put in http://localhost:9000 as URL for your app in TicTail and "run secure code" when starting through TT dev.

Comment: Okay thanks. We are running MSSQL and .NET so maybe I have to find a slightly other way. Any guidance on which parts that could be useful?

Comment: Use the "/native" part as your app and connect it to your own backend. The whole logic for sessions (login/registration) is in app.js. Apart from that you need to reconfigure Restangular to talk to your API instead of the "/server" one in the repo. But as I said, if you don't need to do stuff in the backend, persist products or custom data, it is not required to make the app work. You can handle sessions straight through Angular.

Comment: I am a newbie to Angular so this is a bit overwhelming I must admit :) what does ngTictail do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62680/discussion-between-lowe-backstrom-and-peta).

Answer (score 0):

You can call `angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);` if you want to manually initiate angular. You have to remove the `ng-app`-directive for this to work.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap